# JIRA webhook issue for EPIC status

Tags: jira, gitlab-ci, jira-agile

I was trying to configure a webhook in JIRA which will trigger my gitlab pipeline.

I wanted to trigger the pipeline when EPIC status is **Ready for Go Live** .
Now the problem is pipeline is triggered every time whatever the status (Done,Release testing,Ready for go live,live) of EPIC remains . But I want to get pipeline executed only at a specific status i.e. Ready for Go LIVE.

I wanted help in JQL for this webhook.

Any suggestions on it?

Comment: Hello Karan Kumar! Your question is very unclear and would need some clarification before anyone on this site could help you out. Check out ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information.

Comment: @OmniOwl - I think that is a little unfair. I understood the question being asked.

Comment: @karan  I'm not sure this is possible. I believe that JIRA webhooks only respond to 'updated' events and not to specific transitions.

Comment: @BarnabyGolden I didn't take any action towards the question, I merely pointed out how I saw it. Was trying to be helpful. From my own point of view the question doesn't seem descriptive enough for people to help out. I could of course be wrong :)

Comment: @OmniOwl Fair point!